# Is "in [some period]" different from "within [some period]"?

Tags: prepositions, ambiguity, time, dates

Q1: "I'll finish this job **within** 5 days" definitely means the job is expected to cost 5 days or less. However, does "I'll finish this job **in** 5 days" mean exactly the same?

Q2: Can we say, "I'll finish this job in 5 to 10 days" ?

This question is similar to ["In 15 minutes" or "15 minutes later"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/39340/14594)

Comment: Both versions are vague and can have different interpretations. They are not accurately defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmm. *Within 5 days* means, as you say, in 5 days or a shorter period. *In 5 days* will usually be taken to mean the job will take the whole 5 days and not less.

Yes, *I'll finish this job in 5 to 10 days* allows you a minimum of 5 days and a maximum of 10 days to finish the job.

Comment: Thanks. As Chinese speaker, it is intuitively weird to express the actual meaning of "after 5 days" as "in 5 days". So, do native English speakers say "after 5 days" if they are sure it will cost at least 5 days?

Comment: @JimmChen: It's unlikely that anyone would say 'I'll finish the job after 5 days'. 'I'll have finished the job after 5 days' is possible, but even that is more likely to occur as 'I'll have finished the job in 5 days.'